# I applied sum() on a groupby and I want to sort the values of the last column

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

Given the following DataFrame

```
user_ID  product_id  amount
   1       456          1
   1        87          1
   1       788          3
   1       456          5
   1        87          2
  ...      ...         ...
```

The first column is the ID of the customer, the second is the ID of the product he bought and the 'amount' express if the quantity of the product purchased on that given day (the date is also taken into consideration). a customer can buy many products each day as much as he wants to.
I want to calculate the total of times each product is bought by the customer, so I applied a `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['user_id','product_id'], sort=True).sum()
```

now I want to sort the sum of amount in each group.
Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose `df` is:

```
     user_ID  product_id  amount
0        1         456       1
1        1          87       1
2        1         788       3
3        1         456       5
4        1          87       2
5        2         456       1
6        2         788       3
7        2         456       5
```

Then you can use, `groupby` and `sum` as before, in addition you can sort values by two columns `[user_ID, amount]` and `ascending=[True,False]` refers ascending order of user and for each user descending order of amount:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['user_ID','product_id'], sort=True).sum().reset_index()
new_df = new_df.sort_values(by = ['user_ID', 'amount'], ascending=[True,False])
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
     user_ID   product_id  amount
1        1         456       6
0        1          87       3
2        1         788       3
3        2         456       6
4        2         788       3
```

Comment: what does reset_idnex do?

Answer (score 6):

This would give you the top 5 largest:

```
# n  = number of rows you want to return
df.groupby(['user_id'])['amount'].sum().nlargest(n)
```

Comment: this is to sort whole data frame. This won't help, if you want to sort elements in each group.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `aggregate()`:

```
# Make up some example data
df = data.frame (user_ID = as.factor(rep(1:5, each = 5)), 
                 product_id = as.factor(sample(seq(1:10),size = 25, replace = TRUE)),
                 amount = sample(1:5, size = 25, replace = TRUE))

# Use aggregate with function sum to calculate the amount of products bought by product and customer
aggregate(amount ~  product_id * user_ID , data = df, FUN = sum)
```

Output:

```
   product_id user_ID amount
1           2       1      3
2           4       1      2
3           6       1      1
4           9       1      5
5           1       2      5
6           3       2      9
7           8       2      1
8          10       2      5
9           2       3      5
10          3       3      5
11          4       3      5
12          5       3      3
13          8       3      5
14          3       4      3
15          4       4      9
16          5       4      2
17         10       4      1
18          2       5      1
19          4       5      4
20          5       5      2
21         10       5      2
```